# Add provided dependency to class path when using SBT 0.12.x interactive shell to run app

Tags: scala, sbt

In our project, I would like access to what is a provided dependency at runtime in the sbt interactive console.  It stops one from being forced to deploy to a Storm cluster each time they want to test something.  Are there any options on the 'run' task to accomplish this?

Comment: Thanks for asking this question. I'm wondering this too.  I'll let you know if I find anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I got this working.

First, I created a build.sbt as normal.

Contents of build.sbt in project root directory:

```
name := "Test"
version := "1.0"
scalaVersion := "2.10.1"
resolvers += "Typesafe Repository" at "http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/releases/"
libraryDependencies += "com.typesafe.akka" % "akka-actor_2.10" % "2.1.2"
libraryDependencies += "com.typesafe.akka" % "akka-kernel_2.10" % "2.1.2"
libraryDependencies += "com.typesafe.akka" % "akka-remote_2.10" % "2.1.2"
libraryDependencies += "org.jsoup" % "jsoup" % "1.7.2"
```

Then I ran "sbt console".  This downloaded project dependencies specified in the build.sbt (download output not shown) and starts a Scala shell with the dependencies included on the path.

```
cortland:jjasinski$ sbt console
[info] Set current project to Jazstudios Bot (in build     
file:/Users/jjasinski/Documents/crawler/myproject/)
[info] Starting scala interpreter...
[info] 
Welcome to Scala version 2.10.1 (Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM, Java 1.6.0_37).
Type in expressions to have them evaluated.
Type :help for more information.

scala> import org.jsoup
import org.jsoup
```

I found the information here

http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.12.3/docs/Howto/scala.html